# How to create users in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to use Django's user model, but when I cannot create a new user. I already ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. If I try to run the commands again, I get a "No Changes Detected" message.

I was able to create a superuser for Django admin, and I can use that user to log into my web application using the views that I created, but if I try to create a user, it does not appear in Django admin.

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

views.py for creating the user

```py
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirm = request.POST["confirm"]
        if password != confirm:
            return render(request, "capstone/register.html",{
                "error_message": "Your passwords must match."
            })

        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            return render(request, "capstone/register.html",{
                "error_message": "You will need to pick another username."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

    else:
        return render(request, "capstone/register.html")
```

I have also added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'capstone.User'` to my project's setting.py.

I have also looked at [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/), but it did not help.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for finalproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-fc=64ht^dmr#=ig25b=37o5ux#-s+%lg1+3xc4&y1byug4i6uf'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'capstone',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'finalproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'finalproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: I can see you want to create a customer user model but you have done nothing there, if you are not using that mode, use the default one `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, I added that line like how the answer says, but nothing changed.

Comment: Since you are not using a custom user model, remove this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'capstone.User'` in setting.py

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, I got this error in the console: ```ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'capstone.User.groups'.```

Comment: It looks like you are still using your custom model, can you share the imports that are in views.py by updating your question?

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, I added the imports to my question.

Comment: It looks fine, make sure after removing `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'capstone.User'` in setting.py save the file.

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, the error is still there along with this message: ```HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'capstone.User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'capstone.User.user_permissions'.```. How would I add a ```related_name``` with the pass in the User model?

Comment: I am not sure what customisation you want to do in that custom model, but if you are not using, then completely remove it

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, I want to use the default user model, but that hint message is coming up with the error and am wondering how to fix the clashing that its talking about.

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, I added my settings.py, and I removed the User model from my question, so that my models.py is now empty. After I removed the User model and tried to register then login, I received this error while trying to login ```no such table: auth_user```.

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, I did that and am receiving: ```return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user``` when I try to login or access the admin interface.

Comment: @MathewsMusukuma, I did that, and when I tries to makemigrations and migrate, it said, "No Changes Detected," and the same error message is about auth_user is coming up. I tried deleting the ```db.sqlite3```, but it wouldn't let me.

Answer (score 3):

When you have used the create_user function, you have to first create create_user function in models.py

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    pass

    objects = UserManager()
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

For more Information: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-django-user-model/

Comment: @DarchanVankawala, do you know how to fix this error: ```AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'``` that I am getting while trying to makemigrations?

Comment: Yes you have to modify the User table. please see the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Custom User model with email as the primary identifier field.
    """
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'),max_length=255,unique=True,)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True,null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'),default=False,help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'),
    default=True,
    help_text=_(
        'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
        'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
    ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    uuid_txt = models.CharField(
    _('uuid text'),
    max_length=36,
    unique=True,
    help_text=_(
        'UUID representing this user. '
        'Helps identify this user without their user ID and can be shared 
    publicly.'
    ),
    error_messages={
        'unique': _('A user with that uuid_txt already exists.'),
    },
    )
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(default=None,blank=True, null=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```